# Node JS - TypeError: Cannot read property 'CONTEXT_1' of undefined

Tags: node.js

Filename : orderManager.js

```
const notificationManager = require("./notificationManager");

var orderManager = (function() {

    function orderManager() {
        console.log("orderManager");
    };

    orderManager.bootstrap = function() {
        console.log("orderManager.bootstrap");
        return new orderManager();
    };

    orderManager.prototype.orderContext = {
        "CONTEXT_1": "context_1",
        "CONTEXT_2": "context_2",
        "CONTEXT_3": "context_3"
    };

    orderManager.prototype.notify = function() {
        var dataObj = {};
        notificationManager.sendToClient(dataObj);
    };

    return orderManager;

}());
module.exports = orderManager.bootstrap();
```

Filename: notificationManager.js

```
const orderManager = require("./orderManager");

var notificationManager = (function() {

    function notificationManager() {
        console.log("notificationManager");
    };

    notificationManager.bootstrap = function() {
        console.log("notificationManager.bootstrap");
        return new notificationManager();
    };

    notificationManager.prototype.sendToClient = function(dataObj) {
        console.log("notificationManager.prototype.sendToClient");

        var _this = this;
        switch (_this.request.body.orderContext) {
            case orderManager.orderContext.CONTEXT_1:
                notifyClient(_this, dataObj);
                break;

        }
    };

    return notificationManager;

}());
module.exports = notificationManager.bootstrap();
```

When i try to call **notificationManager.sendToClient()** function from **orderManager.js** file, that will give an error **TypeError: Cannot read property 'CONTEXT_1' of undefined**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot couple both orderManager.js and notificationManager.js tightly.

As per your snippet you are trying to execute `orderManager.notify().`

Your Javascript compilation flow will be like this

- Require orderManager.js
- Require `const notificationManager  = require("./notificationManager");` in orderManager.js
- Require `const orderManager = require("./orderManager");` in notificationManager.js
- Since orderManager.js is not fully executed it is assigned with empty object {} not an instance of orderManager `const orderManager  = {} // Not an instance of orderManager`
- Since empty object is assigned it throws undefined while accessing orderManager.orderContext.CONTEXT_1

Here I modified you snippet and removed the notificationManager.js dependency in orderManager.js

**orderManager.js**

```
  var orderManager = (function() {

        function orderManager() {
            console.log("orderManager");
        };

        orderManager.bootstrap = function() {
            console.log("orderManager.bootstrap");
            return new orderManager();
        };

        orderManager.prototype.orderContext = {
            "CONTEXT_1": "context_1",
            "CONTEXT_2": "context_2",
            "CONTEXT_3": "context_3"
        };

        return orderManager;

    }());
    module.exports = orderManager.bootstrap();
```

**Filename: notificationManager.js**

```
const orderManager = require("./orderManager");

var notificationManager = (function() {

    function notificationManager() {
        console.log("notificationManager");
    };

    notificationManager.bootstrap = function() {
        console.log("notificationManager.bootstrap");
        return new notificationManager();
    };

    notificationManager.prototype.sendToClient = function(dataObj) {
        console.log("notificationManager.prototype.sendToClient");

        var _this = this;
        switch (_this.request.body.orderContext) {
            case orderManager.orderContext.CONTEXT_1:
                notifyClient(_this, dataObj);
                break;

        }
    };

    return notificationManager;

}());
module.exports = notificationManager.bootstrap();
```

**Filename: index.js**

```
const a = require('./notificationManager');
a.sendToClient();
```